# How to return Boolean value from Action Delegate under List.ForEach()

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-types

I am trying to implement following thing. I need to return true if any of the button is found to be changed. I don't want any more looping.

Since ForEach is looking for Action Type Delegate. So is it possible to return bool value from within a deletage

```
public bool AreSettingChanged()
{
    objRpmButtonHolder.RpmButtonCollection.ForEach(btn
        => {
            if (btn.IsChanged)
                return true;
    });
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
public bool AreSettingChanged() 
{ 
    return objRpmButtonHolder.RpmButtonCollection.Any(b => b.IsChanged);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't because that's how the `ForEach` method is defined. In your case you would be better off using the [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) extension method:

```
bool result = objRpmButtonHolder.RpmButtonCollection.Any(btn => btn.IsChanged);
```

Comment: Nice and simple answer, never thought that we have Any function also available.

Comment: Returning from the delegate won't break the iteration.

Comment: @Stephen, that's correct. I will update my answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for another method, like `Find` or `Exists`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool AreSettingChanged()
{
    return objRpmButtonHolder.RpmButtonCollection.Exists(btn
        => { return btn.IsChanged; });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be to use above mentioned Any method, but for more generic approach with returning variables from lambdas you could capture the outside variable and use it as a return result, i.e.:

```
        public bool AreSettingChanged()
        {
            bool changed = false;
            objRpmButtonHolder.RpmButtonCollection.ForEach(btn
                =>
                {
                    if (btn.IsChanged)
                        changed = true;
                });
            return changed;
        }
```

Comment: +1, nice generic solution. Although, in this case, I would really consider a *classic* `foreach` to be more readable than the `ForEach` extension method.

Comment: This solution doesn't break the `ForEach` iteration.

Comment: Generally it shouldn't. As for this particular problem, I already mentioned that using the classic foreach or any of the extension methods specified above would be better.